# FriendlyArm: reset lightdm settings for autologin

Tags: lxde, lightdm

I'm using FriendlyArm on my NanoPi.
I tried to install and launch tigervnc-standalone-server and failed. After that I deleted it with apt autoremove.
But after that my settings for autologin don't work anymore. After launching the device it asks me for a password.
[Here in 6.20](https://wiki.friendlyelec.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_M4#Get_Started) they show that these settings are in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/20-defaultsession.conf`
I have this file and it contains this:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=LXDE
autologin-user=pi
```

But it doesn't work. I tried to put these rows into `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/20-defaultsession.conf` which I created and it doesn't work too.
I have no `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file too.
How can I reset my autologin settings then?